# Probability that only the first person gets their own hat

Tags: probability

This hat matching problem involves 7 people where $A_i$ is the event that the ith person gets their own hat and I need to find the following:

1. Probability that the first and second person get their own hats back but the third and fourth don't:
   $$P(A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c)=P(A_1A_2-(A_3\cup A_4))=P(A_1A_2-(A_1A_2A_3\cup A_1A_2A_4))=P(A_1A_2)-[P(A_1A_2A_3)+ P(A_1A_2A_4)-P(A_1A_2A_3A_4))]$$
   $$P(A_1A_2A_3^cA_4^c)=\frac{1}{(7)_2}- \left[ \frac{1}{(7)_3}+ \frac{1}{(7)_3}-\frac{1}{(7)_4}\right]=\frac{13}{840}$$
2. Probability that ONLY the first person gets their own hat back and the rest don't:
   $$P(A_1A_2^cA_3^cA_4^cA_5^cA_6^cA_7^c)=P\left(A_1- \bigcup_{i=2}^{7} A_{i}\right)=P(A_1)-P\left(A_1\cap\bigcup_{i=2}^{7}A_{i}\right)$$

I get stuck here because I'm not sure how to get that last bit, $P\left(A_1\cap\bigcup_{i=2}^{7}A_{i}\right)$. How do I find that? Also please let me know if I have made an error.

Comment: Part 2 is the probability the first person gets their hat, $\frac17$, times the probability that in a group of $6$ nobody gets their hat, so $\frac17 \times \frac{[6!/e]}{6!}$ where $[\cdot]$ is rounding to nearest integer

Comment: Your $\frac{13}{840}$ looks correct.  I would have done $\frac17 \times \frac16 \times\left(\frac15+\frac35\times \frac34\right)$ where the $\frac15$ is the conditional probability the third person gets the fourth person's hat

Comment: @Henry thank you! would it be correct to say that this is an application of the multiplication rule for conditional probabilities?

Comment: You can look at it that way

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer $6^6/7^7$ ?,  because success = 1/7 so I got $(1/7) * (6/7)^6$ . This is because even during the case of without repetition the probability of success remains same for all the items.

Comment: No.  That would be the answer if the success or failure of each person getting their own hat was independent of the others.  But that is not the case here. If I get the wrong hat, then the person whose hat I get will also get a wrong hat because I already have theirs.